# Scaled-input-trained ML Models

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, feature-scaling

I have input data, the magnitudes vary quite a lot between features. I have scaled them using sklearn's StandardScaler(), then used keras to train a NN on this data to predict my target. I have trained/tested this neural network and it performs well.

Training data is a timeseries of input to a function as such of a bigger model, and my target being a timeseries of output. I have trained the model on scaled input data (off-line), but would like it to replace that function in the model. Then it would take unscaled input data (same features) at each time step and give a good prediction for the target (output).

Being trained on the timeseries data offline, it does not seem best suited to then take unscaled data, one tilmestep a time, which it will have to when used in the model. Should I scale that online-input also (and how to make it consistent with scaled offline input?) or should I e.g. train on unscaled data and use "this optimisation method which performs well with unscaled data"?

Does anyone know how to fix this type of issue?

Comment: My model is in fortran, so I had to use python offline to generate it, fortran to explicitly code it. One option is to extract the "transform" from sklearn, but how do I know how I may extract sklearns transform (for example if for x_1, ... , x_n, x_1 is transformed to x_1/2.5 (say), and x_2=x_2/3.17 and ...)

Could I maybe call something like transform.weights (say), or similar, to extract that transform explicitly so I know how much each is scaled by - so that I can then explicitly code what sklearn scales it by into fortran?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, you should indeed apply the same transformations that you applied when training your model to any new data. For `scikit-learn` you can either use the `pickle` or `joblib` file format to save your transformation steps/pipelines (as described in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)) and then load it again in the script where you are predicting using new data and use the `transform` method to apply the transformations to the new data.